# Android EditText doesn't reappear at the same place

Tags: java, android, xml, android-animation

I'm working on a Credit / Debit card form on Android.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

I have an `EditText` field called `CardNumber` where the user is supposed to type in his / her card number. Upon receiving all the digits of the card number, two additional `EditText` fields, `ExpiryDate` & `CVV` slide out. If the user erases any of the digits in the `CardNumber` field, bot the `ExpiryDate` & the `CVV` fields should disappear or slide in & remove the text written on them.

When the user types in the `CardNumber` again & enters all the digits required, both `ExpiryDate` & `CVV` should appear again **in the same place** they appeared before.

**But this is what I'm getting**

[image]

They are not appearing in the same place. How do I achieve this & how do I remove the text from both `ExpiryDate` & `CVV` upon their disappearance.

**This is what I have done so far**

***MainActivity.java***

```
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.security.Key;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText cardNumber, expiryDate, CVV, nameOnCard;

    private boolean flag = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);//Locks the screen orientation
        init(); //Initializes the variables

        typefunc();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void init()
    {
        cardNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cardNumber); //Field for storing the card number
        expiryDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.expiryDate); //For storing the Expiry Date
        CVV = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CVV); //For storing the CVV
        nameOnCard = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameOnCard); //For storing the name of the Cardholder
    }

    public void typefunc()
    {

        //FORMATTING CARD NUMBER FIELD
        cardNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                if(s.length()==19)
                {
                    //MAKING EXPIRY DATE VISIBLE & PUTTING FOCUS ON IT
                    expiryDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    expiryDate.requestFocus();

                    //SLIDE OUT ANIMATION (FADE IN --> FADE OUT)
                    expiryDate.setAlpha(0.0f);//(INVISIBLE)
                    expiryDate.animate().translationY(expiryDate.getHeight()).alpha(1.0f);//(VISIBLE)



                    //MAKING CVV VISIBLE
                    CVV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    //SLIDE OUT ANIMATION (FADE IN --> FADE OUT)
                    CVV.setAlpha(0.0f); //(INVISIBLE)
                    CVV.animate().translationY(CVV.getHeight()).alpha(1.0f); //(VISIBLE)


                }
                if(s.length()<19)
                {
                    //DISAPPEARING THE EXPIRY DATE 7 CVV
                    expiryDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    CVV.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    //CLEARING THE FOCUS
                    expiryDate.clearFocus();

                    //SLIDE IN ANIMATION (FADE OUT --> FADE IN)
                    expiryDate.animate().translationY(0).alpha(0.0f);
                    CVV.animate().translationY(0).alpha(0.0f);




                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                char space = ' ';

                if(s.length()>0 && (s.length()%5) == 0)
                {
                    char  c = s.charAt(s.length()-1);
                    if(Character.isDigit(c))
                    {
                        s.insert(s.length()-1,String.valueOf(space));
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        //FORMATTING THE EXPIRY DATE FIELD
        expiryDate.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                if(s.length()==5)
                    CVV.requestFocus();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                char slash = '/';
                if(s.length()>0 && (s.length()%3) == 0)
                {
                    char c = s.charAt(s.length()-1);
                    if(Character.isDigit(c))
                        s.insert(s.length()-1,String.valueOf(slash));
                }
            }
        });

        CVV.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                if(s.length()==3) {
                    nameOnCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                if(s.length()==3)
                    nameOnCard.requestFocus();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

***content_main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="payment.ec.juspay.in.cardform.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Credit / Debit"
        android:id="@+id/cardformHeading"
        android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:id="@+id/cardNumber"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:hint="Card Number"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cardformHeading"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cardformHeading"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cardformHeading"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/expiryDate"
        android:hint="Expiry Date (mm/yy)"
        android:maxLength="5"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cardNumber"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cardNumber"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cardNumber"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:id="@+id/CVV"
        android:hint="CVV"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cardNumber"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/cardNumber"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/cardNumber"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nameOnCard"
        android:hint="Name On Card"
        android:layout_below="@+id/expiryDate"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/expiryDate"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/expiryDate"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I missing?

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: try to make expiryDate & CVV invisible instade of Gone, remove their text using expiryDate.setText(""); method

Comment: Doesn't work!  It gives the same output

Comment: I think this is animation problem try setting some fix value in place of "expiryDate.getHeight()" in your condition "if(s.length()==19)"

Comment: Try the same by commenting the setAlpha() & animation() codes & check whether it appears correctly. So that we can confirm whether issue happens because of that.

Comment: @sJy I removed both animation & alpha and it worked. But the requirement is, I have to animate the object with a fading effect

Comment: @Auro did you have a look at my answer? I tried it and it worked. As far as I understand your problem at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to translate the EditText, because that's why it's placed lower on the screen than wanted.

If you anyways want to use a translate animation you have to use View.INVISIBLE instead of View.GONE, otherwise the initial getHeight() will return 0. You also need to translate to 0 for s.length()==19 and to -expiryDate.getHeight() for s.length()<19

```
if(s.length()==19)
{
     //MAKING EXPIRY DATE VISIBLE & PUTTING FOCUS ON IT
     expiryDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     expiryDate.requestFocus();

     //SLIDE OUT ANIMATION (FADE IN --> FADE OUT)
     expiryDate.setAlpha(0.0f);//(INVISIBLE)
     expiryDate.animate().translationY(0).alpha(1.0f);//(VISIBLE)



     //MAKING CVV VISIBLE
     CVV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

     //SLIDE OUT ANIMATION (FADE IN --> FADE OUT)
     CVV.setAlpha(0.0f); //(INVISIBLE)
     CVV.animate().translationY(0).alpha(1.0f); //(VISIBLE)
}
else if(s.length()<19 && expiryDate.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
{
    //DISAPPEARING THE EXPIRY DATE 7 CVV
    expiryDate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    CVV.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    //CLEARING THE FOCUS
    expiryDate.clearFocus();

    //SLIDE IN ANIMATION (FADE OUT --> FADE IN)
    expiryDate.animate().translationY(-expiryDate.getHeight()).alpha(0.0f);
    CVV.animate().translationY(-CVV.getHeight()).alpha(0.0f);
}
```

Additionally you would want to translate the views up in your init method like this

```
expiryDate.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        expiryDate.animate().translationY(-expiryDate.getHeight());
        expiryDate.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh Wow!! It worked man.. Could you please explain the logic behind using `translationY(0)` instead of `translationY(expiryDate.getHeight())` & `translationY(-expiryDate.getHeight())` instead of `translationY(0)`?

Comment: translationY method works relative to the initial position. So in your example you moved the view by expiryDate.getHeight() (positive means down on the screen) down relative to the initial position. In the way I explained above you move the view up by its height before it is drawn. Then you move  it down to the initial postion when it becomes visible (translating to 0 means translate to initial position). You can just try it out by commenting out the setVisibility statements and removing alpha animations.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `View.INVISIBLE` instead of `View.GONE`.

> View.GONE This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.
>
> View.INVISIBLE This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for
>   layout purposes.

Also update the view XMLs from `android:visibility="gone"` to `android:visibility="invisible"` and see if it works.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, but comments doesn't mention that he has tried changing XMLs as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting height from Editext.getHeight(). When the view is not drawn it returns zero. So Second time you get some xx value. So only second time your slideout animation will happen.

If slide out animation is not your preference  use animatelayoutchanges= true for view group. It will animate some standard animations. That will better.

Or you can get height from onPredrawListener.

Thanks